# Customized ListView scrolling - Only Imageviews

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-imageview

I have a ListView in my app with ONLY ImageViews in them. Each row either displays 1, 2 or 3 images depending on a random selection method. But the problem I am facing right now is that when I scroll, the order of the images gets changed, when I want them to stay constant all the time. Plus, the images repeat themselves even though I have used an efficient "int" iterator to retrieve and display the next image in the line.

I have checked other questions dealing with similar problems, but they don't deal with ImageViews. I am a newbie so any help would be appreciated.

```
public class YPAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

public Context context; 
public ArrayList<ImageDetails> flowImages = new ArrayList<ImageDetails>();
LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList mData = new ArrayList();
public int i = Home.getStart();

YPAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ImageDetails> name, int start) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     
    this.context = context; 
    this.flowImages = name; 
}
public void addItem(final int item) {
    mData.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }   
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3;
}
@Override
    public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
    }

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
int x = 0;
    if (Integer.parseInt(mData.get(position).toString()) == 1) x = 0;
    else if(Integer.parseInt(mData.get(position).toString()) == 2) x = 1;
    else if(Integer.parseInt(mData.get(position).toString()) == 3) x = 2;
    return x;
}

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    int mode = getItemViewType(position);



        if(convertView == null)
        {   

        switch(mode){

        case 0:

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_container_1, parent, false);
        if(i < (flowImages.size()))
        {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo_1);

        ArrayList<ImageDimensions> dimensions = new ArrayList<ImageDimensions>();

        dimensions = ImageSorter.getLayout(1);

        // get parameters

                // set image with url

        i++;

        }       

        break;

        case 1:                  
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_container_2, parent, false);          

        if(i < (flowImages.size()-1))
        {
        ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo_2_1);
        ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo_2_2);

        ArrayList<ImageDimensions> dimensions = new ArrayList<ImageDimensions>();

         // get parameters for 2 images

                // set image for first imageview    
        i++;
           // set image for second imageview
           i++;
        }
        break;

        case 2:              
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_container_3, parent, false);

        if(i < (flowImages.size()-2))
        {
        ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo_3_1);
        ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo_3_2);
        ImageView imageView3 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo_3_3);

        ArrayList<ImageDimensions> dimensions = new ArrayList<ImageDimensions>();

       // get parameters for 3 images

                // set image with url for first imageview
        i++;
        // set image for second imageview
        i++;
    // set image for third imageview
               i++;
        }

        break;
    }   
    }


    return convertView;

}



public Object getItem(int position) {
     return mData.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

}

This is the XML for the ListView:

```
<ListView
android:id = "@+id/home_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    >         
</ListView>
```

Comment: Can you show your code in the Adapter and also the List View Item xml

Comment: You need to.post your code (especially your list adapter).  Otherwise we're just guessing how you've implemented this and can't offer anything other than vague potential answers.

Comment: I have added the code you requested. Hope it's clear now. :)

Comment: The Home.getstart() method which I am assigning to i is the index of the first image that I will retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the problem I am facing right now is that when I scroll, the order
>   of the images gets changed, when I want them to stay constant all the
>   time.

That is happening most likely because of the way you setup the `getViewItemType` method(or you try to do it in the `getView` which is wrong). I don't understand how you want your rows types to appear so I can't recommend you something unless you explain better how the rows should appear.

> Plus, the images repeat themselves even though I have used an
>   efficient "int" iterator to retrieve and display the next image in the
>   line.

This is happening because you didn't write the `getView()` method to take in consideration the `ListView`'s recycle mechanism. You should **never setup the data only for the case when `convertView` is null** because this mean that as the `ListView` recycles rows you'll not setup the correct data for the row that is a recycled row.

For example:

```
     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int mode = getItemViewType(position);
        if(convertView == null) {   
            switch(mode){
            case 0:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_container_1, parent, false);
            break;
            case 1:                  
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_container_2, parent, false);          
            break;
            case 2:              
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_container_3, parent, false);
            break;
            }   
        }
        switch (mode) {
        case 0:
                    if(i < (flowImages.size()))
            {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo_1);

            ArrayList<ImageDimensions> dimensions = new ArrayList<ImageDimensions>();

            dimensions = ImageSorter.getLayout(1);

            // get parameters

                    // set image with url

            i++; // I don't know what you try to measure with this variable but 
            // you shouldn't do it in a method like getView as this method is called a lot of times
            // for example the user coculd be playing, scrolling the ListView one item down and one item up for 500 times.
            } 
        break;        
        case 1:
            if(i < (flowImages.size()-1))
            {
            ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo_2_1);
            ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo_2_2);

            ArrayList<ImageDimensions> dimensions = new ArrayList<ImageDimensions>();

             // get parameters for 2 images

                    // set image for first imageview    
            i++;
               // set image for second imageview
               i++;
            }

        break;       
        case 2:

            if(i < (flowImages.size()-2))
            {
            ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo_3_1);
            ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo_3_2);
            ImageView imageView3 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo_3_3);

            ArrayList<ImageDimensions> dimensions = new ArrayList<ImageDimensions>();

           // get parameters for 3 images

                    // set image with url for first imageview
            i++;
            // set image for second imageview
            i++;
        // set image for third imageview
                   i++;
            }


    break;
    }
    return convertView;

}
```

Why do you need to not take in consideration only the `convertView == null` case:

When a `ListView` needs to show a new row(either the first time the list appears on the screen or when the user scrolls up or down) it will call the `getView` method. When one row disappears from the screen the `ListView` may choose to keep that row in a cache to use it later when the `getView` method will be called again(by doing this the `getView` method will not have to build the row again, avoiding creating unnecessary objects). So, in the `getView` method you should always check if the `convertView` is `null`. If it is null then build the rows(and after the null check setup the data). If it isn't null then you have a recycled view and there is no need to build a new row you just have to setup the data on it(if you set the data inside the null check then the recycled view will keep the old data(from a previous position) and you get strange results).

The `getItemViewType` will be called before the `getView` method to let the `ListView` check if it has a recycled view with that type(so you are guaranteed to get the correct recycled view no matter at what position you are). Here I still don't understand how you want to setup the images. You have the `flowImages` list which probably holds your images but I don't know how you want them to be assigned, sequential, random  etc

Comment: Hey, to answer your question about how I want my rows to look - Each row either displays one, two or three images based on the mode. I have a class which returns image dimensions accordingly.  From different tutorials, I saw that the getItemViewType() method is called in the getView() method. I'm not sure how else to use it. Could you suggest a different way? And also the thing about not just handling the case where "convertView==null", I'm still not clear about that.

Comment: Oh, the number of images displayed in a row is randomized. I set this up in an arraylist before the adapter is called. I pass this into the adapter and use it to determine the number of images each row must have. That's what I do with the mData variable.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this condition
    if(convertView == null)